# Удаление элементов из json-словаря по ключу (Python)

Tags: python, json, словарь

Есть json-словарь 'full_dataset' (см.картинку ниже), и есть список с именами файлов 'train_dict', содержимое которого `'['COCO_train2014_000000000009.jpg','COCO_train2014_000000000025.jpg',... и тд]'`.

Нужно сверить словарь со списком, и удалить все записи из словаря, в поле `'filename'` которых записаны значения НЕ из списка. Проще говоря, удалить записи об отсутствующих изображениях, тем самым получив словарь, в котором описываются изображения только из списка `'train_dict'`.

Использовал такую конструкцию, но судя по всему нужно делать по-другому. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как будет верно, заранее спасибо!

```
for i in full_dataset['images']:
    if i['filename'] not in train_dict:
       del i
```

[image: Текст]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал наоборот: создал новый список, в котором только словари, где значение по ключу `'filename'` есть в списке.

```
full_dataset['images'] = [image_info for image_info in full_dataset['images']
                          if image_info['filename'] in train_dict]
```

Comment: Просто и изящно, благодарю)